# Do I have to use node to run a puppeteer package?

Tags: puppeteer

I am implementing an application with Javascript and html that will be executed in browser. In my application I would like to use puppeteer for Web Scraping. I put the puppeteer code in js file, but it doesn't work. Is it possible to run puppeteer  in java scrip running in browser or it has to be executed by node?

Answer (score 3):

You can't run Puppeteer without Node.js, Puppeteer **IS** a node.js library, the first line of the docs says

> Puppeteer is a Node library